# Too much power consumption in iOS

Tags: iphone, battery

Some Users are complaining that my app is using too much power. 
My app is using GPS services background mode. I know that it is the reason for too much battery consumption. But still i would like to know if there is some thing by which i can reduce the power consumption without effecting the performance ?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Re-think your logic. Reduce the update rate of GPS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are only requiring the accuracy that you really need. So, if you don't need the accuracy that gps supplies, but can do with less accurate location services then only add the 'location-services' string to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your apps Info.plist file and leave out the 'gps' key. Also, make sure the accuracy you use in locationManager.desiredAccuracy reflects only the lowest accuracy that you really need.